# Value of the `href` in the DOM element is different than the value in React component.

Tags: reactjs

i am getting a weird issue with ReactJS.

I am rendering a list of buttons on the page where users can click and see their invoices. However, the value of the `href` in the DOM element is different than the value passed to the React component.

To help you understand what's going on, there is a screenshot of React element.
[image]

And this is how it looks after rendered to HTML
[image]

As you can see, DOM hash are identical but the value of `href` are different.

Below is the part of the React code. `ButtonBase` is just a UI component I use through out the website.

```
const renderInvoices = () =>
    map(invoices.sort(descendingOrder), invoice => (
      <Invoice key={invoice.invoiceNumber} {...invoice} />
    ));

const Invoice = ({
  invoiceNumber,
}) => (
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ButtonBase
        href={`/invoices/${invoiceNumber}.pdf`}
        target="_blank"
      >
        View
      </ButtonBase>
    </td>
  </tr>
);
```

Any idea why this is happening? This has been bugging me for past couple days.Any advices are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How can we figure out what's going on if we don't know your code and the data you are working with?

Comment: Since you mention lists, it may have something to do with how React reconciles components, but impossible to tell without knowing the code.

Comment: hey thanks for the comments. I have added some codes

Comment: `key={invoice.invoiceNumber}` looks good. Unclear what's happening. Please provide a [mcve].